# Self form action displaying php Code with in the code

Tags: php, html, forms

I am developing a PHP code regarding of registration.
I came to know that self form action is secure rather than going to another form action page.
When I created form action, values are inserting into database, but my problem is again PHP CODE was also printing in the above section.

This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
      ob_start();
      session_start();
      if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
      header("Location: index.php");
      }
    include 'dbconfig.php';
     $error = false;
     extract($_POST);
        error_reporting(0);

     ## :: Registration :: ##

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
    $fname          =   $_POST['fname'];    //gets firstname from frontend
    $lname          =   $_POST['lname'];    //gets lastname from frontend
    $email          =   $_POST['email'];    //gets email from frontend
    $password       =   $_POST['password']; //gets password from frontend
    $cpassword      =   $_POST['cpassword'];    //gets Confirm password from frontend
    $mobile         =   $_POST['mobile'];   //gets mobile from frontend
    $class          =   $_POST['class'];    //gets class from frontend
    $remote         =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //gets the ip address from user


 $reg_query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `at_reg_user`(`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`, `cpassword`, `mobile`, `class`, `ipaddress`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$password1','$cpassword1','$mobile','$class','$remote')");
      if ($reg_query) {
     header('Location: index');
     $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
    unset($fname);
      unset($lname);
   unset($email);
   unset($password);
    unset($cpassword);
   unset($mobile);
   unset($class);

      } else {
    $errMSG = " Not Successfully registered, you may login now";
     }
 }


 }
  ?>
```

This is my form action code

```
        <form  method="post" action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' >
    <div class="form-group"> <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $fnameError;  ?></span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-fname">First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="fname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $lnameError;  ?></span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="lname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $passwordError; ?></span>  <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $passwordmError; ?></span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"><?php echo $cpasswordError; ?></span>  <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $cpasswordmError; ?></span>   <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo $mcpasswordError; ?>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password"  name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-cpassword form-control" id="cpassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"><?php echo $mobileError; ?></span>
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-mobile">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="number" maxlength="10" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number..." class="form-mobile form-control" id="mobile">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><span class="text-danger"><?php echo $classError; ?></span>
        <select name="class"  for="form-class" class="form-class form-control id" id="class">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">------Select Class------</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" id="submit">Sign me up!</button>
</form>
```

The problem is "its again redirecting to index page successfully but the above php code is displaying

Comment: Sorry but it's can't understand, what you need. so please explain to another way

Comment: You should place an `exit();` after your `header();` call. This will stop further execution of the script and will prevent displaying anything that happen later in your code. Also when you do this you will have to place your redirect below the code that inserts the data into the database

Comment: The values from html form are succesully inserting into my database but the above php code is printing in my html page

Comment: after successful insertion redirect like this header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
die;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove **"ob_start();"** from the php file..